# count occurrences of unique string row by row

Tags: r

say I have a df like so:

```
number date
123    2022-01-01
567    2022-01-01
123    2022-01-04
763    2022-01-05
567    2022-01-06
123    2022-01-09
```

I want to count the occurrence of each number by expanding the range row-by-row. so my expected output would be

```
number date        occurrence
123    2022-01-01  1
567    2022-01-01  1
123    2022-01-04  2
763    2022-01-05  1
567    2022-01-06  2
123    2022-01-09  3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### base R

```r
dat$occurrence <- ave(dat$number, dat$number, FUN = seq_along)
dat
#   number       date occurrence
# 1    123 2022-01-01          1
# 2    567 2022-01-01          1
# 3    123 2022-01-04          2
# 4    763 2022-01-05          1
# 5    567 2022-01-06          2
# 6    123 2022-01-09          3
```

### data.table

```r
library(data.table)
as.data.table(dat)[, occurrence := seq_len(.N), by = number ][]
#    number       date occurrence
#     <int>     <char>      <int>
# 1:    123 2022-01-01          1
# 2:    567 2022-01-01          1
# 3:    123 2022-01-04          2
# 4:    763 2022-01-05          1
# 5:    567 2022-01-06          2
# 6:    123 2022-01-09          3
```

---

Data

```r
dat <- structure(list(number = c(123L, 567L, 123L, 763L, 567L, 123L), date = c("2022-01-01", "2022-01-01", "2022-01-04", "2022-01-05", "2022-01-06", "2022-01-09")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2):

row number plus group by should do it.

```r
library(tidyverse)

example_data <- read_table('number date
123    2022-01-01
567    2022-01-01
123    2022-01-04
763    2022-01-05
567    2022-01-06
123    2022-01-09')


example_data |> 
  group_by(number) |> 
  mutate(occurance = row_number())
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#> # Groups:   number [3]
#>   number date       occurance
#>    <dbl> <date>         <int>
#> 1    123 2022-01-01         1
#> 2    567 2022-01-01         1
#> 3    123 2022-01-04         2
#> 4    763 2022-01-05         1
#> 5    567 2022-01-06         2
#> 6    123 2022-01-09         3
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Might be worth adding an `ungroup()` to the end to avoid unexpected behaviour in subsequent code (unless the `|>` pipe somehow handles that - haven't seen it before)

Comment: The `|>` will have no effect on the groups: it's the native-R pipe and in addition to being unaware of most package internals, it is a bit more limited than the more "popular" (until perhaps R-4.1) `magrittr::%>%`. I agree, adding `ungroup()` is a good practice to get into, since follow-on `mutate`/`summarize` and other actions will behave differently or at least less-efficiently.

Comment: The grouping cause is still useful sometimes, the group is very explicitly show on the print statement as well, this is the same discussion I have had on loading the tidyverse instead of just dplyr I am purposefully trying to expose new users to what I believe is a better way of handling data